# Angular "PUT" edit select multiple

Tags: angular

I am trying to edit a user, I already recover the user in my table but, my question is how I can show in my select multiple table the elements that were selected

```
 getUserDetail(iduser : number){
    this.GetGroups();
    this.serviceuser.UserDetail(iduser).then((u : User)=>{
      this.users = u;
      const form = this.FormUserUpdate.setValue({
      username : this.users.username,
      email : this.users.email,
      idgroups : this.users.groups,
      })
      console.log(this.users);        
    })

  }
```

That is my code to retrieve the user in the form, but how can I get the marked groups out?

```
  GetGroups() {  
    this.servicegroup.getGroup().then(res => this.groups = res);  
  }
```

And here I call the service to return the groups

```
<div >
              <label for="idgroups">Grupos</label> 
              <select multiple formControlName="idgroups" class="form-control">  
                <option *ngFor="let group of groups" value={{group.id}}>  
                        {{group.name}}  
                </option>  
            </select>  
            </div>
```

This is my html as they will realize it only shows all the groups, but how could I do to mark out the groups that the user had?

[image]

What I want is what I leave marked the groups that have those users in addition to the other existing groups

Comment: (`editar` does not (yet?) seem to be an English word.)

Comment: Sorry, I speak Spanish, the word was to edit

Comment: More details please.

Comment: So, what version of Angular do you use, to correctly target the audience? I think 2+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiple-select)

You set you **idgroups** as array of objects. It should be array of **numbers**, because as a value of option you use **group.id**:

```
  <option *ngFor="let group of groups" value={{group.id}}>  
                        {{group.name}}  
  </option>
```

In here

```
 getUserDetail(iduser : number){
    this.GetGroups();
    this.serviceuser.UserDetail(iduser).then((u : User)=>{
     ...
      idgroups : this.users.groups,
      })
      console.log(this.users);        
    })

  }
```

replace to:

```
 getUserDetail(iduser : number){
        this.GetGroups();
        this.serviceuser.UserDetail(iduser).then((u : User)=>{
       ...
          idgroups : this.users.groups.map(gr => gr.id), // =>[1,2...5]
          })
          console.log(this.users);        
        })

      }
```